# RegEx in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

When I do

```sql
SELECT resrev_meta FROM resourcerevs WHERE resrev_meta LIKE '%attr%';
```

I get results like this

```xml
<attr><fileid>131</fileid></attr> 
<attr><fileid>326</fileid><width>360</width><height>640</height></attr>
```

**Question**

Is it possible to have a RegEx that would only output the number between `<fileid>` and `</fileid>`?

Comment: do you want only the fieldid even if there are multiple attributes ?

Comment: Yes, only the fileid if possible.

Comment: I had a similar problem and was elated to find out that mysql supported XPATH expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex is probably not what your looking for.  mysql supports xpath expressions.

This should give you what you need:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(resrev_meta,'//fileid')  AS fileid 
     FROM resourcerevs 
     WHERE resrev_meta LIKE '%attr%';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   ExtractValue('<a>ccc<b>ddd</b></a>', '/a') AS val1,
    ->   ExtractValue('<a>ccc<b>ddd</b></a>', '/a/b') AS val2,
    ->   ExtractValue('<a>ccc<b>ddd</b></a>', '//b') AS val3,
    ->   ExtractValue('<a>ccc<b>ddd</b></a>', '/b') AS val4,
    ->   ExtractValue('<a>ccc<b>ddd</b><b>eee</b></a>', '//b') AS val5;

+------+------+------+------+---------+
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5    |
+------+------+------+------+---------+
| ccc  | ddd  | ddd  |      | ddd eee |
+------+------+------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

No, not using regex. Mysql doesn't support regex-based replacement or group matching etc.

The only regex support is [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) or [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) (they are synonyms), which is used to match a column value.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can do something hacky like this if you want (pardon the long lines):

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(
    resrev_meta,
    INSTR(resrev_meta, '<fileid>') + LENGTH('<fileid>'),
    INSTR(resrev_meta, '</fileid>') - INSTR(resrev_meta, '<fileid>') - LENGTH('<fileid>')) AS fileid
FROM resourcerevs WHERE resrev_meta LIKE '%attr%';
```